# Sending a request and receiving a response in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express

Hi I am new to Node JS and trying to understand the working of client server communication.

File on Server- (express.js)

```
  app.post('/action', (req, res) => {
    const status = action.doAction(req);
  });
```

AJax Call on Client :

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/action',
  data: foo.getJSON(),
  success: () => {
    console.log('Action done');
  }
});
```

My ajax call send a JSON data and server side implements some function which does further action and returns true or false.

But on success on client side console there is nothing printed. Also, I want to understand that how can I send data i.e. status back to client from Server by response object and how can I receive it and print on client side. Also, I want to print which is in success after completing all the action in my doAction function which takes about 2-4 seconds.
 Can somebody explain how to achieve all this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. doAction should use a callback or promises if you expect the action to take time, but I can only guess without seeing the code
2. In your app.post, you will need to send the data back to the client (how else would they get it?), and this is documented quite clearly in the Express docs:

   ```
     app.post('/action', function(req, res){
       const status = resultOf.action.doAction(req);
       res.send(status);
     });
   ```

Comment: that is okay, I just posted this question to understand the working. There is no problem statement for me. It's just to understand the basic points.

Comment: Also, I wanted to ask that is there some way to call a function in Node server with AJAX call without url attribute?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get your code running try this

`app.post('/action', (req, res) => {
    res.send('request done');
  });`

NodeJS is non-blocking. So you need promises or async/await to process data in `doAction()`